# Executing VB code when a cell is clicked?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following table:

```
<table>
  <tr><th>Firstname</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Peter</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Lois</td></tr>
</table>
```

The goal is when a user clicks inside a td tag to execute a VB ASPX function. How I can do this?

Comment: http://outbottle.com/asp-net-html-element-onclick-and-onserverclick-client-side-validation/

Comment: There's no `OnClick` server event for `<td>`. You can use JavaScript on load though...

Comment: you can use an ajax call to a web method. So just google the two and you ll get your answer. Use jquery to handle the `<td>` click event and make an ajax call

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery, and add `onclick="$.get('action.aspx');"` to the `td` tag, and put the function you want to execute in `action.aspx`.

Comment: Please provide an example.

Comment: @MATH000: `<td onclick="$.get('action.aspx');">Peter</td>`

Comment: I am not sure if your answer works. But if it does is it not easier to bind the click event from jquery itself: `$(function(){$('td').on('click',function(){ $.get('action.aspx');})});`